# Subscriber method with the On prefix

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

In c# there is a naming convention that a method that raises an event should start with the **On** prefix. For example, if I have an event named `MyEvent` the method which invokes that event should be named `OnMyEvent`. My question is: Would it be considered a violation of the naming convention to have a subscriber method with the **On** prefix. **Example**:
`Enemy` has an event named `EnemyKilled`. `RoundManager` class has several methods that should be subscribed to the event: Instead of subscribing/unsubscribing them individually

```
Enemy.EnemyKilled += (args) => _enemiesKilled++;
Enemy.EnemyKilled += SpawnNewEnemy;
Enemy.EnemyKilled += UpdateStat;
```

I can have a method named `OnEnemyKilled`:

```
void OnEnemyKilled(EnemyKilledArgs args)
{
    UpdateStat(args);
    SpawnNewEnemy();
    _enemyKilled++;
}
```

which will be subscribed/unsubscribed instead:

```
Enemy.EnemyKilled += OnEnemyKilled;
Enemy.EnemyKilled -= OnEnemyKilled;
```

Would it be considered a bad practice or violation of the naming convention to have a subscriber method named `OnEnemyKilled`? Note that the `Enemy` already has the `OnEnemyKilled` method which raises the `EnemyKilled` event.

Comment: I think the answers to your question will be opinion-based. E.g. ReSharper proposes such names for the event handlers.

Comment: As far as I remember that convention only refers to the "firing" side of the event. Nobody stops you from naming the subscriber "OnXXX". I wouldn't do it, but that is up to you (and/or your team).

Comment: How would you name the method? I'm always struggling to find a short and  descriptive name for a field or method.

Comment: How about "EnemyKilledEventHandler". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-events , where that's more for the delegates, but I'd still prefer that over OnEnemyKilled. In a former project, the Team Convention would have been "EnemyKilledFired" ... but as dynamoid said, all very opinionated.